# cocos2d on iphone v2.2 : crash apparently linked to framework

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, crash, crash-reports

I got this crash on my device, trying to test my app, but i can't understand how this is linked to my dev code. Can you help me please ?
I had similar crashes on other iphone devices as well : iphone5 and 5s. Can you explain me how to try to debug this?
Thank you very much

```
Incident Identifier: D91872AA-E456-4D25-9CB1-D611C03E8BC2
CrashReporter Key:   b00e52b6212cbb2b7c42058e73db72df143b48c0
Hardware Model:      iPhone6,2
Process:             PandaWar2 [1642]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/BB3CBBD8-E5CC-4898-8829-D29CB758E2E8/PandaWar2.app/PandaWar2
Identifier:          com.terrassestudio.PandaWar2
Version:             1.0
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-03-01 20:52:32.837 +0100
Launch Time:         2015-03-01 20:48:54.055 +0100
OS Version:          iOS 8.1.2 (12B440)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   GLEngine                        0x29f4a99b gleRunVertexSubmitARM + 887
1   GLEngine                        0x29f48b71 gleSetVertexArrayFunc + 117
2   GLEngine                        0x29f00663 glDrawElements_ACC_ES2Exec + 807
3   OpenGLES                        0x29f86dcd glDrawElements + 37
4   PandaWar2                       0x00087a2f -[CCParticleSystemQuad draw] (CCParticleSystemQuad.m:451)
5   PandaWar2                       0x0017d509 -[CCNode visit] (CCNode.m:583)
6   PandaWar2                       0x0017d4dd -[CCNode visit] (CCNode.m:579)
7   PandaWar2                       0x0017d473 -[CCNode visit] (CCNode.m:568)
8   PandaWar2                       0x00164aa7 -[CCDirectorIOS drawScene] (CCDirectorIOS.m:163)
9   PandaWar2                       0x0016644d -[CCDirectorDisplayLink mainLoop:] (CCDirectorIOS.m:532)
10  QuartzCore                      0x2a4df7ff CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 95
11  QuartzCore                      0x2a4df667 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 363
12  IOMobileFramebuffer             0x2ed85829 IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 89
13  IOKit                           0x284cf4df IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 255
14  CoreFoundation                  0x2755f0a3 __CFMachPortPerform + 131
15  CoreFoundation                  0x2756f571 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 33
16  CoreFoundation                  0x2756f50b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 343
17  CoreFoundation                  0x2756db0d __CFRunLoopRun + 1605
18  CoreFoundation                  0x274bb3bd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 473
19  CoreFoundation                  0x274bb1cf CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
20  GraphicsServices                0x2e8790a5 GSEventRunModal + 133
21  UIKit                           0x2aacaf9d UIApplicationMain + 1437
22  PandaWar2                       0x000a2e5b main (main.m:14)
23  libdyld.dylib                   0x35310aad start + 1

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x353c32a0 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x352fc9fd _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 277
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x352f220f _dispatch_mgr_thread + 35

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x353d79cc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x35451ea9 _pthread_wqthread + 789
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x35451b80 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x353d79cc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x35451ea9 _pthread_wqthread + 789
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x35451b80 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x353d79cc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x35451ea9 _pthread_wqthread + 789
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x35451b80 start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: Latest stable version is 3.4. Why don't you update it?

Comment: @Nikita : because of the effort for such a forklift update ... maybe ? The API keeps getting mangled at each minor release, imagine the hop you are suggesting. Also, upgrading the framework seems like the old 'windows' remedy : why dont you reboot. This happens in the update cycle, the root cause could easily be in OP's code.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg And the root cause could very well be an issue that was resolved is a subsequent release. Early versions of Cocos2d were quite buggy and many of those bugs have been addressed in recent builds.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help, i've seen that there are more recent releases, but it seems the gap is huge (another branch?). If you tell me it's worth upgrading, i'll do it! Is my current code going to be compatible with the new version of Cocos2d 3.4?